# JQuery Click event not firing on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnApplyFilter').click(function () {
            alert("JQuery Running!");
        });
    });
```

The above function is not getting fired on button click. What would be the cause?

My Button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnApplyFilter" runat="server" Text="Apply Filter" OnClick="btnApplyFilter_Click" />
```

Comment: Could you see anything in `console` ? Why do you have `inline OnClick` ?

Comment: try removing the onclick

Comment: @guradio, Even if inline click handler is invalid..`jQ` event binding would work..

Comment: Why you have second OnClickc in html?

Comment: your JS is probably failing here `OnClick="btnApplyFilter_Click"`, you cant call a function like that, where are the brackets....check your console for errors

Comment: @RayonDabre i see just tried it i got `btnApplyFilter_Click is not defined` but alert did show :)

Comment: @guradio, Exactly.. My assumptions hardly go wrong :P

Comment: @RayonDabre could be something else unless OP check for error we cant help. maybe `$` error :)

Comment: @guradio, Most likely.. Developer should always keep _Developer tools_ open!

Comment: or maybe you did not include Jquery, so the code inside document ready doesnt execute.....can you please show me your console errors

Comment: @Rayon @guradio @Luth it was nothing related to OnClick event. As I am using asp.net, the control ID gets changed and I needed to get the clientID of My Button for jQuery to work. Here is how I did that. ` $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=btnApplyFilter.ClientID%>').click(function () {alert("JQuery Running!");
        });
    });` Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: ``OnClick="btnApplyFilter_Click"`` should be something in your server-side..I think it will be C#?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Remove onClick from button

There is no use of onClick in button

> 2. Write the function delegately if its a dynamic element

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click','#btnApplyFilter',function () {
            alert("JQuery Running!");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

The `OnClick` is for server side event. You can use `OnClientClick` if you want to call a javascript function or also you can use jQuery click event.

Comment: This whole question is about client side code. `OnClientClick` is totally irrelevant. Non of the tags include `ASP.NET`.